# convert element.parentProperty.childProperty to array syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Question 1:**

Is `element.property` equals `element[property]`?

If answer to question 1 is true then

**Question 2:**

How to write `element.parentProperty.childProperty` in array syntax as mentioned above in question 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can access `element.property` as `element["property"]`.

To answer your second question you can write it as `element["parentProperty"]["childProperty"]`

To demonstrate the code, a sample snippet has been attached

```js
var x = {
  y: {
    z: 'Test'
  }
};

alert(x["y"]["z"]);
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. You made it to look so easy.